# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent Reationship Not Quite Right

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have two tables - both of which are legacy.

One table, countries, has just v fields:

```
entry (index field)
Countryname
Abbrev
```

My other table is PCustomers which (amongst others) has

```
Reference (index field)
country (the foreign key)
```

I have two models set up:

```
class Countries extends Model
{
    protected $table="Countries";
    protected $primaryKey = 'entry';

    function pcustomer()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\PCustomer','country','entry');
        }
}
```

and

```
class PCustomer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'p_customers';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Reference';

    public function country()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Countries','entry','country');
        }

    public function addnew(Request $request)
        {

        }
}
```

To try this out I placed in a controller:

```
public function PCustomers()
        {
            $customer = PCustomer::find(5955)->country;
            dd($customer);
        }
```

I know 5955 exists and its country is 74.

The dd returns 74, but nothing else.

If I drop the country so it becomes

```
$customer = PCustomer::find(5955);
```

I get the usual and correct collection with the full fields.

What I thought should happen is with ->country I would get the details of the record plus the 3 fields from country, rather than just 74.

Help appreciated!

Comment: I found I can get this with the following line:

`$customer = PCustomer::where('Reference',5955)->with('country')->get();`

but this seems at variance with the documentation.

Comment: No, if you do `->country` then only the country record will be returned. This is the expected behavior. Your solution is correct, except that you better replace `get()` with `first()` since you're only expecting one record. Sure you can stick with what you did but it will return a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections) instead of a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can get this with the following line:

```
$customer = PCustomer::where('Reference',5955)->with('country')->get();
```

but this seems at variance with the documentation